# Node on RosAndroid is not receiving images from PC

Tags: ros, ros-master-uri, ros-ip, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys, I have created a node on android to subscribe to a topic for images from PC. PC publishes images continuously & node on android phone subscribes for images. I have set the right IP to  both ROS_MASTER_URI & ROS_IP as suggested here,
http://answers.ros.org/question/72145/android-tutorial-pubsub-doest-subscribe-from-a-pc-node/
Still I am unable to achive it.
So please let me know the solution, if anybody has here.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200400/node-on-rosandroid-is-not-receiving-images-from-pc./) by [stark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20255/stark/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-01-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Somehow network setup with ROS Android seems to confuse many users.

We'll need some more information:

1. Real Android device, or simulator
2. Version of ROS, ROS Android & Android itself
3. Network setup (LAN, WAN, etc)

Also, just to be clear: are you trying to subscribe on your Android device to topics published by your PC, or is the PC trying to subscribe to topics published by your Android device?

---

Edit: assumptions:

1. you're using a physical Android device - *not* the simulator
2. and both your ROS pc and the Android device are on the same network (a simple home LAN)
3. you have checked that the Android device and the ROS pc have working IP connectivity
4. you checked the Android application and that it is able to connect to ROS masters *other than its own*

Make sure your ROS pc has `ROS_IP` set to its own IP, and that `ROS_MASTER_URI=http://$ROS_IP:11311/`. In most cases, a home LAN doesn't have proper DNS for the pc and/or the Android device, resulting in strange behaviour. Setting `ROS_IP` should work around that.

On the Android device, make sure to use the `ROS_MASTER_URI` with the IP address of the master (pc), *not* its hostname.

Once the Android node should be connected, use `roswtf`, `rosnode` and `rostopic` to diagnose your graph.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20255/stark/) on 2015-01-07**:
I am trying to subscribe on android device. PC publishes images continuously..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2015-01-07**:
Could you update your original question with the other information?

**Comment by [stark](https://answers.ros.org/users/20255/stark/) on 2015-01-07**:
All your assumptions are correct.I am able to run android_pubsub tutorial successfully, but i am facing this problem with image_transport tutorial. I will now try to diagonise praph..